# Analyze in Excel is Slow

Tags: excel, powerbi, refresh

I am using Analyze in Excel for some reports on the service to create pivots and send to customers. Some reports are taking forever to create a pivot whilst others arent taking too long. I am getting the 'running OLAP query' message at the bottom of excel. Is there any way to speed this process up? Can we stop refreshing the data each time a field is added to the pivot?

Thanks

Yasir

Comment: Have you turned off automatic calculation? Have you considered other programs to do analysis - such as SAS for example?

Comment: all my calculations are used in power bi. I have turned this feature off in excel but its still taking some time